# Is there any way to convert scale i.e. number after decimal point in databricks sql?

Tags: sql, database, databricks, databricks-sql

Is there any way to convert scale i.e. number after decimal point in databricks sql?

let's say there is a field name NUM1 whose datatype is predefined as `number(38,2)`. Now, I need to map it to NUM2 with `number(38,5)`

I did like `round(num1,5) as num2` but its not working.

expected result:

| num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- |
| 38.25 | 38.25000 |

Can someone help me on this?
Actually I need do some calculations on that number with the result set to 5 digit after decimal point. Even when I do square of num1 it's giving digit with 2 scale only.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? Isn't 38,25 the same number as 38.25000? Are you expecting rounding errors on subsequent operations? Or what else is the issue you want to address? If this is just about displaying your numeric data, this is something that you should usually care about in your GUI, not in SQL.

Comment: Actually I need do some calculations on that number with the result set to 5 digit after decimal point. Even when I do square of num1 it's giving digit with 2 scale only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CAST?

```
SELECT NUM1, CAST(NUM1 AS DECIMAL(38, 5)) AS NUM2
FROM your_table;
```

You may need to cast all parts of a calculation e.g.

```
( cast(12,34 as decimal(15,5)) / cast(3.45 as decimal(15,5)) )
```

and/or apply to the overall

```
cast( (12.34 / 3.45) as decimal(15,5))
```

then to display that you need to ensure default formatting isn't truncating what you see in the result

Comment: Yeah I have tried it and it's not working

Comment: Not working" isn't very helpful I'm afraid. Did you get an error message? Or an unexpected result? Can you describe what actually happened please.

Comment: It seems like the result is automatically converted into decimal(38,2) since the input was  predefined.

Comment: you may need to cast all parts of a calculation e.g. `( cast(12,34 as decimal(15,5)) / cast(3.45 as decimal(15,5)) )`  and/or apply to the overall `cast( (12.34 / 3.45) as decimal(15,5))`  then to display that you need to ensure default formatting isn't truncating what you see in the result

Comment: Thanks it works when casting from the beginning